# JRuby and Generics

Tags: jruby

I have the following java code:

```
nameFinderModel = NameFinderME.train("en", "organization",
        sampleStream, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
```

And my conversion is as follows:

```
nameFinderModel = NameFinderME.train("en", "organization", sample_stream, {})
```

Is this an adequate conversion or am I missing something?  Are there any general guidelines for converting generics to JRuby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a correct conversion. Just remember that Java erases generics at compile time. To quote [the documentation](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby):

> If a Java class is defined with Java generics, the types are erased during compilation for backwards compatibility. As a result. JRuby will have problems with automatic type conversion. For example, if you have a `Map<String,String>`, it will be seen as a simple `Map`, and JRuby will not be able to determine the correct types using reflection.

Comment: "will not be able to determine the correct types". What is the resulting behavior at runtime?